JWT Decode is throwing NullReferenceException
I'm creating basic Authentication using JWT in ASP.NET Core MVC ver. 6. After I logged in I set the token to the session, whenever I go to dashboard I check that token by sending an AJAX requests to the controller. From controller I validate that token.
The problem is, the Decode function is keep returning

NullRefferenceException

Even though I just hardcoded the token there.
I'm using this package:
JWT .Net
Here is my ajax from dashboard :
function checkToken() {
    //var token = sessionStorage.getItem("loginSession");
    var data = {
        token: sessionStorage.getItem("loginSession")
    };
    console.log(data)
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Auth/Validate',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }

    })

}

Here the inside of controller :
using JWT.Algorithms;
using JWT.Serializers;
using JWT;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using FrontEnd.ViewModel;
using NuGet.Common;

namespace FrontEnd.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Forgot()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public string Validate([FromBody]AuthVM authVM)
        {
            //var token = authVM?.token;
            //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            //{
            //    throw new ArgumentException("Token is null or empty");
            //}
            var token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFzZEBlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJuYW1lIjoiTGFydWUgTW9ociJ9.l37wEV8ttLXBW5pMa8dMj7iAz6eWnaqiMbG93gpUOzA";



            IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm();
            IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
            IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();

            
            IDateTimeProvider provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
            IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
            IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder, algorithm);


            var payload = decoder.Decode(token);

            return payload;

        }
    }
}


and the ViewModel :
namespace FrontEnd.ViewModel
{
    public class AuthVM
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
    }
}


As you can see, I send the token from Ajax requests, I retrieve it via view model called AuthVM
I can retrieve it by calling authVm.token it throwing an NullReferenceException error. Then I tried to hardcode the token it still returns that error.
Am I declaring the wrong decode function ?
Here is the stack trace I get from the error
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=JWT
  StackTrace:
   at JWT.JwtDecoder.<>c.<AllKeysHaveValues>b__20_0(Byte[] key)
   at System.Array.TrueForAll[T](T[] array, Predicate`1 match)
   at JWT.JwtDecoder.ValidSymmetricAlgorithm(Byte[][] keys, String decodedPayload, IJwtAlgorithm algorithm, Byte[] bytesToSign, Byte[] decodedSignature)
   at JWT.JwtDecoder.Validate(JwtParts jwt, Byte[][] keys)
   at JWT.JwtDecoder.Decode(JwtParts jwt, Byte[][] keys, Boolean verify)
   at FrontEnd.Controllers.AuthController.Validate(AuthVM authVM) in C:\Users\Redactedhehe\source\repos\UniversityAPI\FrontEnd\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 54



If you are using a HMACBased algorithm, you probably need to provide some sort of secret/key? This is also where error seems to be pointing to. I don't know that library, so I can only suggest you to have a look at the documentation on how to provide this key.

How did you create this JWT in the first place? You are definitely missing the secret to decode it.

Well you can certainly decode it without a key (at least manually without that library), because the header and the payload (first and second part of JWT) is just base64 encoded json. But you cannot verify the signature ...

looking at the docs for that package there appears to be a fluent API that would potentially allow you to decode the token without validating it.

@phuzi While that might be possible, in the scenario of authentication (which this seems to be) I'd certainly suggest to not accept a JWT without validating its signature.

@derpirscher I'm reading the docs it didn't pass the key, so I thought this is what they do in ASP, but then I tried to pass the key and it works

Maybe if I'm using the IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new RS256Algorithm(certificate); algorithm it dont need a key?

Well, you have to use the the algorithm that fits the algorithm given in the header of the token. In your case the token is signed with HS256, which should be HMACSHA256

@derpirscher I already declare the algorithm, and passed it to the decoder, its jus I thought in ASP you won't need key to decode the token because I thought it stored on the cache of the program or something, so the author didn't pass the key on the decode function

so I just discovered that there is algorithm that doesn't need a private key as mentioned in auth0.com
In the case of the RS256 algorithm, the verifier should not have the private key that signs a JWT. It would only need to have the public key.

You seem to have quite little knowlege on the principles and different algorithms in symmectric and asymmetric encryption/signing. I don't know where you get this token form, but the token you show in your question is clearly signed with HS256 algorithm, thus for verifying it, you have to use the same algorithm and the same secret that was used to sign it. RS256 is a completely different algorithm

yeah its been a while since I use JWT, I generate it from other project (API) with HS256 and I just copy paste the decode function in the docs that I forgot that I use HS256 for the algorithm, thus I need the key to validate it

so, after I read the required parameter of the decode function carefully, it can be passed by more than 1 parameter, that is not explicitly explained in the docs.
In this case I'm using HS256 so I need to pass the secret key, but in the documentation using example is using RS256A algorithm that doesn't need a secret key but a public key based on the comment of this page ,
So, in this case, I'm passing 3 parameter including the key
IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
IDateTimeProvider provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm();
IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder, algorithm);
var key = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Secret");

//IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder, algorithm);


var payload = decoder.Decode(token, key, verify: true);

Then I can wrap them in the try catch to return the response
